# BeautifulSoup picking up div objects in some download requests but not others

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm using python's bs4 module to parse HTML. However, I've run into a peculiar bug.

When downloading page HTML's for parsing, I've noticed BS4 will recognize div objects in some pages but not others, even though the specific object I'm referencing is present in both and the paths are the same.

e.g.

```
<div class = "item" data-year = "19-20">
     <div class = "irrelevant">...</div>
     <div class = "irrelevant">...</div>
     <div class = "stats-grids">...</div>
     <div class = "irrelevant">...</div>
</div>
```

I've done some digging and see it frequently proposed that something like this can be caused by Java use in the webpage, and not showing up in the HTML. However, I believe this not to be true in this case because BS4 is correctly identifying the path in other instances where the code remains unchanged.

When using...

```
res = requests.get('examplesite.com')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

element = soup.select('div[data-year = "19-20"] > div[class = "stats-grids"]')
```

For some pages, from the same website, element is correct. Other times, it can find div[data-year = "19-20"] and div[class = "stats-grids"] independently of one another, but not when I specify that one is the child of the other.

In other words, it's there, but only when I specify that stats grids is within the data year, it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may occur due to the site having incorrect HTML (for example a tag is not closed).

Try using *[html5lib](https://pypi.org/project/html5lib/)*. It will attempt to create a well-formed HTML document by adding additional tags.

Install it using

```
pip install html5lib
```

and specify it in the BeautifulSoup constructor

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html5lib')
```

**Ref:**
[Differences between parsers](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers)

Comment: This fixed it. Had no idea this was a potential hurdle with BS4.Thank you for your help!